# Laravel 5.5 where() result is not expected

Tags: laravel, where-clause

Laravel 5.5 DB code:

```
DB::table('users')->where('company_id', 'ACB')->toSql()
```

I expect result as

```
SELECT * FROM `users` where `company_id` = `ACB`
```

But, I got following result;

```
select * from `users` where `company_id` = ?
```

What I did wrong ?
Thanks

Comment: This syntax prevent to sql injection. But when you try  `DB::table('users')->where('company_id', 'ACB')->get()` that case actual query is `select * from users where company_id ='ACB'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing is wrong,
the `toSql()` method, will only show you the query with binding params.

If you want to show bind, you need to use `query->getBindings()`.

This is a security, to prevent SQL injection
Databuilder use  a prepared statement with question mark placeholders.

Look at [this PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)